# How to extract number 19 in "Not Visible 19" using powershell ? regex will be better i guess.

Tags: powershell-2.0

How to extract number 19 from below text using powershell ?

06A8    07E:0  Not Visible                19  (M)     51206

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a regex is probably easiest.

```
$s = "06A8 07E:0 Not Visible 19 (M) 51206"
if ($s -match "\s[[A-Za-z\s]+(\d+)") {
    $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: the problem that I am facing is, If this line is a text I get the correct output. But if I am providing this regex at the commandline during the output I get the complete line instead of 19 . Does regex responds to string and non string differently ?

Comment: symaccess -sid xxxx list devinfo -init ig_xxxxx |grep -pattern "((?<=Not Visible\s.*)\w+)" . I get the complete line. which is in the example pasted above in the question. However if I assign the output to a variable with type string . I get the correct value with my regex and yours.